# Dynamically change option values in drop down list

Tags: php, jquery

Hi I want to add multiple drop down lists to my html page. Which they are contained same option values. (name,email,state,city,country,phone) condition is when user select "name" in first drop down list it should be disabled in all other drop down list. Assume when user select "email" in second drop down list, both email and name should be disabled in other drop down lists. 
I only select one option value for one drop down list.
Previously selected option values should be disable in other drop down lists.

please can anyone help me???

Comment: ajax, can't add much to that, your question is overly broad.

Answer (score 3):

Something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/NW7QC/2/ .  But instead of test, get the values from the other select elements.